# While using table view xib constant space is getting left when i configure it in table view

Tags: xcode, tableview, xib, space

actually i want to add xib cell on table view after giving all constraint 0 from all side the constant space remain there so please help me out that how can i remove that space.[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmOrs.png]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That space is because the constraint to margins is checked, try removing the check from add constraints to margins keeping the values to zero.

Answer (score 1):

Please uncheck Constrain to margins at the time of giving constriants otherwise automatically it will give default 8 pixels.

[image]